# Separar dados de uma variável

Tags: r

Eu tenho uma variável - (Município),que me traz o resultado (Açucena - MG). Como faço para separar no R o Município do Estado?

```
library(sidrar)
Tab1612SojaRend <-get_sidra(1612,variable = 112, period = c("last" = 22),geo ="City",
                        classific = 'c81',geo.filter = list("Region" = 3),
                        category = list(2713))
 head(Tab1612SojaRend)
 $`Abadia dos Dourados - MG`
 Município (Código)                Município Ano (Código)  Ano
 2             3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         1996 1996
 3             3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         1997 1997
 4             3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         1998 1998
 5             3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         1999 1999
 6             3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2000 2000
 7             3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2001 2001
 8             3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2002 2002
 9             3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2003 2003
 10            3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2004 2004
 11            3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2005 2005
 12            3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2006 2006
 13            3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2007 2007
 14            3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2008 2008
 15            3100104 Abadia dos Dourados - MG         2009 2009...
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código pra gente?

Comment: `strsplit('Açucena - MG', ' - ')`.

Comment: O meu comentário acima só functiona se `class(Municipio)` for `"character"`. Se for `"factor"` tem que ser `strsplit(as.character(Municipio), ' - ')`.

Comment: Obrigado Rui, só que eu tenho um problema com a separação '-', porque tem alguns municípios que possuem '-'. Não tem alguma função, tipo a fórmula direita,esquerda do excel?, que aí eu pediria os 2 últimos character.

Comment: Albertt, não coloquei o código porque é muito grande

Comment: Note que a separação não é `'-'`, tem espaços antes e depois, `' - '`. Assim deve funcionar mesmo que a cidade tenha `'-'` sem espaços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `sub_str` do pacote `stringr` permite que separemos uma string no `R` de acordo com o seu número de caracteres e as respectivas posições deles. Por exemplo, para `Açucena - MG`, temos 12 caracteres:

```
Açucena - MG
123456789012
```

(as dezenas foram omitidas por razões óbvias)

Para separar a cidade dos estados, basta então pegar a string `Município` e remover os últimos 5 caracteres: `espaço`, `-`, `espaço`, `estado`. Como o tamanho da string varia por cidade, eu criei uma função para automatizar isso:

```
separarCidade <- function(x){

  n <- nchar(x)  
  cidade <- str_sub(x, 1, n-5)

  return(cidade)

}

head(separarCidade(unique(Tab1612SojaRend$Município)), 10)
 [1] "Abadia dos Dourados" "Abaeté"              "Abre Campo"         
 [4] "Acaiaca"             "Açucena"             "Água Boa"           
 [7] "Água Comprida"       "Aguanil"             "Águas Formosas"     
[10] "Águas Vermelhas"
```

Utilizei `head` e `unique` acima só pra mostrar como a função opera em nomes de cidades diferentes. No teu caso, o correto é rodar `separarCidade(Tab1612SojaRend$Município)` para separar os nomes das cidades que aparecem repetidas.

O que a função `separarCidade` faz é calcular o número de caracteres de cada município e, a partir disso, retirar a substring que vai do começo até o enésimo-5 caracter.

Comment: Vou testar aqui. Obrigado Marcus Nunes por mais esta ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

Esta função separa a cidade e o estado mesmo que a cidade tenha hífen `'-'` e tem como saída uma lista com cidades e estados.
O vetor para testes tem uma cidade fictícia, com hífenes onde na realidade não existem.

```
s <- c('Abadia-dos-Dourados - MG', 'Açucena - MG')


separar <- function(x, sep = "-"){
  separador <- paste0(sep, "[^-]+$")
  cidade <- sub(separador, "", x)
  cidade <- trimws(cidade)
  separador <- paste0("^.*", sep, "([^-]+$)")
  estado <- sub(separador, '\\1', x)
  estado <- trimws(estado)
  list(cidade = cidade, estado = estado)
}

separar(s)
#$cidade
#[1] "Abadia-dos-Dourados" "Açucena"            
#
#$estado
#[1] "MG" "MG"
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui. Obrigado Rui, por mais esta ajuda.